# Nextflow process only working with first tuple element

Tags: tuples, bioinformatics, nextflow

I am currently developing a small Nextflow (v.22.10.6.5843) pipeline for running vcfancestralalleles.jar in several files. To do so, I decided to use a tuple. However, when I run the process it is only executed in the first element of the tuple.

**Here is my channel definition:**

```
Channel
        .fromPath(params.input_ihs)
        .splitCsv(header:true)
        .map{ row -> [ row.chromosome, file(row.path_vcf), file(row.path_genetic_map), file(row.path_ancestral), file(row.path_manifest)] }
        .set{samples_ihs}
```

**Here is my DSL2 process definition:**

```
publishDir "${results_dir}/ancestral_annotation", mode:"copy"

    input:
    tuple val(chromosome), path(path_vcf), path(path_genetic_map), path(path_ancestral), path(path_manifest)
    file java_script

    output:
    tuple val(chromosome), path("chr${chromosome}_aa.vcf")

    """
    samtools faidx ${path_ancestral}

    java -jar ${java_script} \
    -m ${path_manifest} \
    ${path_vcf} |\
    bcftools annotate -x '^INFO/AA' > chr${chromosome}_aa.vcf
    """
}
```

**Here is my workflow definition: **

```
workflow {
    p1 = vcf_ancestral_annotation(samples_ihs, java_script)
 }
```

**
And here is my input_ihs file:**

```
chromosome,path_vcf,path_genetic_map,path_ancestral,path_manifest
21,/mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/test/data/ihs_files/21.phased.with.ref.vcf,/mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/test/data/ihs_files/chr21.b38.predicted.map,/mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/nf_modules/ancestral_fasta/ANCESTOR_for_chromosome_GRCh38_21_1_46709983_1.fa,/mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/nf_modules/manifest_annotation/manifest21
22,/mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/test/data/ihs_files/22.phased.with.ref.vcf,/mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/test/data/ihs_files/chr22.b38.predicted.map,/mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/nf_modules/ancestral_fasta/ANCESTOR_for_chromosome_GRCh38_22_1_50818468_1.fa,/mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/nf_modules/manifest_annotation/manifest22
```

At the beginning I thought it was a problem with the input_ihs file. However, If I run:

```
samples_ihs.view()
```

I can see that the tuple actually contains the two elements of the input_ihs file:

```
[21, /mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/test/data/ihs_files/21.phased.with.ref.vcf, /mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/test/data/ihs_files/chr21.b38.predicted.map, /mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/nf_modules/ancestral_fasta/ANCESTOR_for_chromosome_GRCh38_21_1_46709983_1.fa, /mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/nf_modules/manifest_annotation/manifest21]
[22, /mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/test/data/ihs_files/22.phased.with.ref.vcf, /mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/test/data/ihs_files/chr22.b38.predicted.map, /mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/nf_modules/ancestral_fasta/ANCESTOR_for_chromosome_GRCh38_22_1_50818468_1.fa, /mnt/c/Users/fernanda_miron1/Documents/pop_north_developing/nf-selection/nf_modules/manifest_annotation/manifest22]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues like this almost always involve the use of [multiple input channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#multiple-input-channels):

> When two or more channels are declared as process inputs, the process
> waits until there is a complete input configuration, i.e. until it
> receives a value from each input channel. When this condition is
> satisfied, the process consumes a value from each channel and launches
> a new task, repeating this logic until one or more channels are empty.

You've probably used a [factory method](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#channel-factory) to create your *java_script* channel, but I think you just need to make sure it is a [*value channel*](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel). Note that a value channel is implicitly created by a process when it's invoked with a simple value. You could instead try the following for example:

```
params.java_script = '/path/to/vcfancestralalleles.jar'

...

workflow {

    java_script = file( params.java_script )

    Channel
        .fromPath( params.input_ihs )
        .splitCsv( header:true )
        .map { row ->
            [ row.chromosome, file(row.path_vcf), file(row.path_genetic_map), file(row.path_ancestral), file(row.path_manifest)]
        }
        .set { samples_ihs }

    p1 = vcf_ancestral_annotation(samples_ihs, java_script)
}
```